# How to make an anonymous public async task

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a method I have made that returns a object as a list. Down the line I realized I had to join a few tables for my result. The problem comes in my return statement which states:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<> to System.Collections.Generic.List<>.

How can I fix my code so that I can return my joined results? Here is my code:

```
public async Task<List<McaMswcomapnionAuditCardPinrecords>> SearchPinRecords(string Region, [FromQuery] PaginationDTO pagination)
{

    var queryable = (from pinRecords in context.McaMswcomapnionAuditCardPinrecords
                     join transitRecords in context.AbmProdRegionTransitRecordsNew on pinRecords.TransitRecordId equals transitRecords.Id
                     join transitDescription in context.CommonTransitRecords on transitRecords.TransitRecordId equals transitDescription.Id
                     where pinRecords.RegionRecordId == Region && pinRecords.AuditComplete == false
                     select new
                     {


                     }
                     );

    await HttpContextExtensions.GetPage<McaMswcomapnionAuditCardPinrecords>(queryable, pagination.Page, pagination.QuantityPerPage);
    return await queryable.Paginate(pagination).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: You need to define a "real" type to return from the method (i.e. a non-anonymous type). You can't use anonymous types like that.

Comment: The title doesn't really match the body of the question. It seems like you're asking how to create an anonymous public *type*, not *task*. I doubt it matters whether it's async or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Remarks section in the documentation for Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types#remarks) says:

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object. The compiler provides a name for each anonymous type, although your application cannot access it.

That tells us two things:

1. The compiler is creating a class for you, based on how you define the anonymous type. So you aren't saving any processing time or memory by not creating a class yourself. And,
2. You cannot access the auto-generated name of the anonymous class, so you cannot define a method that returns that type. (you could cast to `object` and return `List<object>`, but that just makes things more difficult)

The solution is to just create a named class yourself with all the properties you intend to return, and return that type instead.

```
public class RecordWithDescription {
    public int TransitRecordId { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    // etc.
}
```

```
public async Task<List<RecordWithDescription>> SearchPinRecords(string Region, [FromQuery] PaginationDTO pagination)
{

    var queryable = (from pinRecords in context.McaMswcomapnionAuditCardPinrecords
                     join transitRecords in context.AbmProdRegionTransitRecordsNew on pinRecords.TransitRecordId equals transitRecords.Id
                     join transitDescription in context.CommonTransitRecords on transitRecords.TransitRecordId equals transitDescription.Id
                     where pinRecords.RegionRecordId == Region && pinRecords.AuditComplete == false
                     select new RecordWithDescription
                     {
                         TransitRecordId = pinRecords.TransitRecordId,
                         Description = transitDescription.Description,
                         // etc.
                     }
                     );

    await HttpContextExtensions.GetPage<McaMswcomapnionAuditCardPinrecords>(queryable, pagination.Page, pagination.QuantityPerPage);
    return await queryable.Paginate(pagination).ToListAsync();
}
```

(I didn't test this code, so you may need to tweak it, but it gives you the idea)